# What is correct suffix for scss files in rails 6

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I have an application that has been upgraded through rails 2 to rails 6.  I am finding that in rails 6 the order of precedence of the style sheets is changing depending on the development machine on which the application is running.  Currently I have an `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`, and my stylesheets are a mixture of `.scss` files and `.css.scss`.  I also have at the top of my `application.css.scss` the following:

```
/*
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
*= require actiontext
*= require_self
*/
```

What is causing the order of precedence to change.  Should I change all the files to `.scss`?

Comment: Make sure you are only using SASS `@import 'foo';` directives and not sprockets directives like `*= require_tree .`. The later causes big problems since each file is individually sent through the sass compiler and then concatenated. I'm not sure the naming actually matters.

Comment: I think you put your finger on it, I do have sprocket directives. I have added these into question. Can I just replace each of these with an ```import``` directives.

Comment: Yes and no. `@import` directives are used by the sass compiler to load other files. This works well with libraries that are built with sass or just consists of a single css file. It will run into problems if you have a dependency that uses sprockets directives to load its subfiles.

Comment: This has to be handled on a per dependency basis. You can find instructions for actiontext at https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html

Comment: I did originally do as specified in that action text guide, but it did not work. I may have made a simple mistake, so will try again later tonight. If that does not work can I just remove the ```require_self``` directive? Would you like to combine your comments into an answer, or will I do that?

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself. `require_self` is really just a spockets directive that lets you change the order of inclusion so that you can place the code in that file relative to the other sprockets directives. You don't want to use it with SASS.